# Laravel Queues, Job does not exist when it does

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, jobs, laravel-cashier

Using Laravel 8 for a project,

I've got a webhook configured from stripe, which hits an endpoint in my app when a payment is made, and sends a job to the queue. However the job is not being processed and I'm getting the following error:

`Spatie\StripeWebhooks\Exceptions\WebhookFailed: Could not process webhook id '5' of type ' because the configured jobclass 'App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\HandleChargeableSource' does not exist. in /Users...`

however the class DOES exist:

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
//app/Jobs/StripeWebhooks.php (example copied from https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks#handling-webhook-requests-using-jobs)

<?php

namespace App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall;

class HandleChargeableSource implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /** @var \Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall */
    public $webhookCall;

    public function __construct(WebhookCall $webhookCall)
    {
        $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // do your work here

        // you can access the payload of the webhook call with `$this->webhookCall->payload`
    }
}
```

and then in config/stripe-webhooks.php:

```
//config/stripe-webhooks.php

<?php

return [
    /*
     * Stripe will sign each webhook using a secret. You can find the used secret at the
     * webhook configuration settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks.
     */
    'signing_secret' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'),

    /*
     * You can define the job that should be run when a certain webhook hits your application
     * here. The key is the name of the Stripe event type with the `.` replaced by a `_`.
     *
     * You can find a list of Stripe webhook types here:
     * https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types.
     */
    'jobs' => [
        'invoice_payment_succeeded' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\HandleChargeableSource::class,
        
    ],

    /*
     * The classname of the model to be used. The class should equal or extend
     * Spatie\StripeWebhooks\ProcessStripeWebhookJob.
     */
    'model' => \Spatie\StripeWebhooks\ProcessStripeWebhookJob::class,
    
    /*
     * When disabled, the package will not verify if the signature is valid.
     * This can be handy in local environments.
     */
    'verify_signature' => env('STRIPE_SIGNATURE_VERIFY', true),
];
```

should also add that I've tried `composer dump-autoload` which came up with the following, not sure if it's even related `Class App\Jobs\HandleChargeableSource located in ./app/Jobs/StripeWebhooks.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

Comment: Did you run the queue worker ?

Comment: Yes!! That's what's throwing up the error - job goes into 'failed jobs' table

Comment: Did you register jobs in `stripe-webhooks.php` ? Ex: [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks#handling-webhook-requests-using-jobs)

Comment: Hi @Eklavya, yes in `stripe-webhooks.php` i've got ```'jobs' => [
        'invoice_payment_succeeded' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\HandleChargeableSource::class,
        // 'source_chargeable' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\HandleChargeableSource::class,
        // 'charge_failed' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\HandleFailedCharge::class,
    ],```

Comment: replace namespace with `namespace App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks;` because `HandleChargeableSource` is currently in `namespace App\Jobs` which is wrong

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya, but it's still having the same error. I've copied the template from the example you sent over earlier, but still same error

Comment: Update your question with minimal reproducible code. (All related code with jobs) Error message is clear your Job class not found means your job class path obviously wrong

Answer (score 1):

please replace the namespace to `namespace App\Jobs;`
replace the job array class in stripe-webhooks.php file to `\App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks::class`